# Recycle Adapter positioning issue

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

i am using recycle adapter to popualte my data. The issue is when i scroll down the same data is being populated example:

`05-28 20:52:09.626  adding key: setting the holder - position :0
05-28 20:52:10.533  adding key: setting the holder - position :1
05-28 20:52:10.569  adding key: setting the holder - position :2
05-28 20:52:10.916  adding key: setting the holder - position :3
05-28 20:52:11.214  adding key: setting the holder - position :4
05-28 20:52:11.494  adding key: setting the holder - position :5
05-28 20:52:11.789  adding key: setting the holder - position :6
05-28 20:52:12.033  adding key: setting the holder - position :4
05-28 20:52:12.037  adding key: setting the holder - position :5
05-28 20:52:12.041  adding key: setting the holder - position :6
05-28 20:52:12.099  adding key: setting the holder - position :7
05-28 20:52:12.212  adding key: setting the holder - position :8
05-28 20:52:13.052  adding key: setting the holder - position :9
05-28 20:52:13.340  adding key: setting the holder - position :10
05-28 20:52:13.739  adding key: setting the holder - position :11
05-28 20:52:14.185  adding key: setting the holder - position :12
05-28 20:52:14.227  adding key: setting the holder - position :13
05-28 20:52:14.481  adding key: setting the holder - position :14
05-28 20:52:14.851  adding key: setting the holder - position :15
05-28 20:52:15.032  adding key: setting the holder - position :12
05-28 20:52:15.041  adding key: setting the holder - position :13
05-28 20:52:15.044  adding key: setting the holder - position :14
05-28 20:52:15.069  adding key: setting the holder - position :15
05-28 20:52:15.174  adding key: setting the holder - position :16
05-28 20:52:15.843  adding key: setting the holder - position :17
05-28 20:52:16.181  adding key: setting the holder - position :18
05-28 20:52:16.599  adding key: setting the holder - position :19
05-28 20:52:16.631  adding key: setting the holder - position :20
05-28 20:52:16.913  adding key: setting the holder - position :21
05-28 20:52:17.378  adding key: setting the holder - position :22
05-28 20:52:17.693  adding key: setting the holder - position :23
05-28 20:52:18.082  adding key: setting the holder - position :24
05-28 20:52:18.498  adding key: setting the holder - position :25
05-28 20:52:18.844  adding key: setting the holder - position :26
05-28 20:52:19.236  adding key: setting the holder - position :27
05-28 20:52:19.713  adding key: setting the holder - position :28
05-28 20:52:19.926  adding key: setting the holder - position :25
05-28 20:52:19.928  adding key: setting the holder - position :26
05-28 20:52:19.948  adding key: setting the holder - position :27
05-28 20:52:19.972  adding key: setting the holder - position :28
05-28 20:52:20.010  adding key: setting the holder - position :29
05-28 20:52:20.783  adding key: setting the holder - position :30
05-28 20:52:20.995  adding key: setting the holder - position :31
05-28 20:52:21.178  adding key: setting the holder - position :32
05-28 20:52:21.537  adding key: setting the holder - position :33
05-28 20:52:21.908  adding key: setting the holder - position :34
05-28 20:52:22.335  adding key: setting the holder - position :35
05-28 20:52:22.607  adding key: setting the holder - position :33
05-28 20:52:22.609  adding key: setting the holder - position :34
05-28 20:52:22.611  adding key: setting the holder - position :35
05-28 20:52:22.657  adding key: setting the holder - position :36
05-28 20:52:22.891  adding key: setting the holder - position :37
05-28 20:52:23.757  adding key: setting the holder - position :38
05-28 20:52:23.968  adding key: setting the holder - position :39
05-28 20:52:23.996  adding key: setting the holder - position :40
05-28 20:52:24.285  adding key: setting the holder - position :41
05-28 20:52:24.643  adding key: setting the holder - position :42
05-28 20:52:25.134  adding key: setting the holder - position :43
05-28 20:52:25.388  adding key: setting the holder - position :44
05-28 20:52:25.680  adding key: setting the holder - position :45
05-28 20:52:26.050  adding key: setting the holder - position :46
05-28 20:52:26.345  adding key: setting the holder - position :47
05-28 20:52:26.759  adding key: setting the holder - position :48
05-28 20:52:27.060  adding key: setting the holder - position :49
05-28 20:52:27.112  adding key: setting the holder - position :46
05-28 20:52:27.114  adding key: setting the holder - position :47
05-28 20:52:27.116  adding key: setting the holder - position :48
05-28 20:52:27.134  adding key: setting the holder - position :49
05-28 20:52:27.311  adding key: setting the holder - position :50`

As u can see sometime the position is being repeated even though i am scrolling down Ex: position 4,12

I cannot paste the source code because it is confidential

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

```
rv.addOnScrollListener(new EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener(linearLayoutManager) {
                @Override
                public void onLoadMore(int current_page) { // when we have reached end of RecyclerView this event fired
                    if (canMakeRequest()) {
                        //load more data and notify adapter
                    }
                }
            });
            //load data and set adapter
```

Comment: post your code where you set the adapter for the first time and when you update it later

Comment: without your code is impossible to help.

Comment: added code to the main question

Answer (score 1):

Override getItemViewType  and return position in your recyclerview Adapter and everything will be fine.

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

Comment: Nope not working

Comment: well you'll have to paste the adapter code then..

Comment: Sorry sir cant do that . But thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

My guess, for assumption you have one textview to populate list of name in recyclerview means, in **bindViewHolder()** function you need to update textview every time.

Suppose you have **if()** condition to update data, then there should be **else** condition for alternate value to update textview otherwise it shows the previous data only.

Comment: but how can i avoid it ? . As i have to check if it is null else i simplely update it

Comment: then remove the **null** value from list itself and there is no other way

Comment: okie will try that